# Search for a word or phrase in the file doesn't work for XML

Tags: windows, xml

When I try to search whether a particular word or phrase if exists in any of the text or other files in a particular folder, it works finely .. but When I try the same method with XML, Windows isn't able to do it. I think it cannot go through XML files.

How to overcome this bug of windows???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want XML text to be indexed, you can try and assign the XML extension to use the plain text filter.

To do that, go to Control Panel / Folder Options / File Types tab, and change the Open With handler to notepad.

That said, I never use Windows Search because I find it to be somewhat broken.
I can recommend instead the free [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home).

Comment: Accepted [15 chars]

Answer (score 0):

One hack would be this : [How to change the extension of all selected files at once?](https://superuser.com/questions/147918/how-to-change-the-extension-of-all-selected-files-at-once)

just copy all the files in a new folder (ensuring no harm done to the original files). And perform search operation after changing the extension.

Comment: This was a temporary fix of the issue.