# How to change the extension of all selected files at once?

Tags: windows, batch, file-extension

Its possible to rename files all at once. But its not possible to change the extension of selected files all at once.

If windows doesn't support this facility .. then is there any batch script or something to work out with ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command prompt example:

```
rename *.html *.htm
```

will rename all files with `.html` extension in the current directory to `.htm`

Comment: yup. this is much satisfying :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/index.htm) that allows mass renaming in many ways...

Comment: Only for Windows, but **Total Commander** is an awesome tool for replacing the classic **Windows File Manager**. Small (around 5MB), portable, free (purchasing not obligatory), and constantly updating since the old times of Windows 95. Greatly adviced.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can do this `rename 's/\.doc$/.rtf/' *.doc`

The above renames all files with `doc` extension to the `rtf` extension